# WMI class properities return different values with C# and VBS...which one is correct?

Tags: c#, vbscript, wmi

I have a class in C# which fetches properity with Name `SKU`  from WMI class "`root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ComputerManagement11:SqlServiceAdvancedProperty`" 
as

> PropertyName : SKU  PropertyNumValue : 2702571241

But when i fetch the same property through VB Script the result is as follows.

> PropertyName: SKU PropertyNumValue: -1592396055

Which is the correct value?

What is the conversion happening with it?

Comment: Where is the code, esp. the vbscript code?

Comment: One's treating a 32-bit value as an *unsigned* integer, and getting `2702571241`. The other is taking those same 32 bits and treating them as a *signed* integer - `-1592396055`.

Comment: This makes sense. on further investigation i found that WMI datatype for the same property is CIM_UINT32 which interim treated as unsigned in C# and Signed in VBS.

Comment: Based on your input simle unboxing helped to convet in c#,
`(int)Convert.ToUInt32(m.Properties["PropertyNumValue"].Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are the same, a four-byte (DWORD) value which appears as `A115F6E9` in hex.

Your C# code treats this either as an unsigned integer  while your VBScript treats this as an *signed* integer. You can use both values in their respective languages.

If you want to compare the result against a constant though, you should define the constant using HEX notation in both languages, eg `0xA115F6E9` in C# and `&HA115F6E9` in VBScript

In fact, Eric Lippert wrote [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/12/03/integer-arithmetic-in-vbscript-part-two.aspx) about this a while ago, explaining how to convert from the negative number to the Hex value in VBScript.